# System Restart Causes CSS to Render Improperly in Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, controller, rendering, restart

My computer automatically updated in the middle of the night forcing my computer to shut down. After I restart my rails app I am encountering considerable issues surrounding my CCS and as well as several controllers. For example, I am unable to scroll through any pages, my menu icons are not rendering at all, and several objects are rendering incorrectly. Additionally the few links I can access are encountering errors as many of my methods are no longer recognized. I am new to Rails and unsure of where to start to address these issues. Any guidance would be appreciated (I have restarted my server several times).

Comment: I've been looking around and it seems the issue may be that there is a service that needs to be restarted but I am unsure what this may be. Again any ideas as to what may lead to the issue above is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error it appears the problem was solely in the rendering of specific CSS elements (these elements were obscuring login elements of the site which led to issues with methods that required a user to be logged in) As far as I can tell an update somewhere in my system caused elements to render in a different order (leading to some being hidden) and a fixed position attribute on the header to be applied to the entire page, hence the inability to scroll. After adjusting to these new parameters the sites seams to be working as before.

Answer (score 0):

if it's in development environment you can use

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

if it's production you can use

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

after you run this command above make sure you restart rails server , you don't need to restart whole Operating system just rails server.

Comment: I ran the suggestions you noted above but am not getting any improved functionality in my app. I am still getting a screen that almost seems like it is frozen.